# How collisions are handled in java LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap, hash-collision

I know that in HashMap collisions are handled using LinkedList at each index if there is a collision the new node is inserted at the end of LinkedList but in the case of LinkedHashMap we use a doubly-linked list but to maintain order here the next and prev references are already occupied now how collisions are handled?

Comment: Does the doumentation not answer this? Why not just read [the source code](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/LinkedHashMap-source.html)?

Comment: Also, if the DLL is used to track insertion order (so that the map entries can be enumerated back in the same order they were inserted), what difference does a collision make? Where the item ends up being inserted/tracked by the map is of little consequence to the device that, separately to the map, tracks the order of insertion of items

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedHashMap` is primarily concerned with establishing a linked list to manage the `bucket` access of the map. But since `LinkedHashMap` subclasses `HashMap` which subclasses `AbstractMap`, those ancestral classes are still used to handle multiple values per bucket (i.e. collisions).